# Как работает этот код (Девид Фленеган)?

Tags: javascript

Читая книгу Девида Фленегана наткнулся на такой код

```
var isArray = Function.isArray || function(o) {
 return typeof o === "object" &&
 Object.prototype.toString.call(o) === "[object Array]";
};
```

Этот код по смыслу определяет функцию для проверки типа переменной на массив. Но я не понимаю зачем нужна вот эта штука:
`Function.isArray ||` . Нуждаюсь в объяснении, в интернете поиски этого не увенчались успехом.

P.S Название для заголовка очень плохое и я понимаю, но ничего не могу с этим поделать.

Update:

1. Несколько человек тут ответили мол смотри как работает булева логика. Но я знаю как она работает (ленивое вычисление слева направо)
2. Отдельное спасибо `@andreymal` он проникся то о чем я и спрашивал.

Update 2:

Вообщем в следующей главе есть такой же код:

```
Array.join = Array.join || function(a,sep) {
 return Array.prototype.join.call(a,sep);
};
Array.slice = Array.slice || function(a,from,to) {
 return Array.prototype.slice.call(a,from,to);
};
Array.map = Array.map || function(a, f, thisArg) {
 return Array.prototype.map.call(a, f, thisArg);
}
```

Этот код нужен для того чтобы определить собственные функции? И если они определены не переопределять? Тогда почему не написано так `Array.prototype.join ||`, `Array.slice = Array.prototype.slice ||`, `Array.map = Array.prototype.map ||`?

Comment: добавь конкретнее, что за книга и в какой главе этот код

Comment: @Grundy Глава 7.10 Тип Array

Comment: а книга как называется?

Comment: Да, это обычная опечатка. Выше по тексту речь идет об `Array.isArray`

Comment: @Grundy ага понятно, гляньте я добавил еще один интересный фрагмент (больше ничего добавлять не буду это уже окончательная версия)

Comment: `Array.join` и т.д. - это статические функции, то есть коллекция передается как параметр.

Comment: @Grundy да это-то понятно. Просто в чем смысл тех функций с булев сложением? Если написать в консоли `Array.isArray` мы получим функцию и все правильно так как эта функция находится в конструкторе Array. Но а здесь же вроде то же самое? Только если вызвать одну из функций `Array.join` то мы не получим функцию как тогда потому что она находится в прототипе. Но если мы выполним код: `Array.join = Array.join || function(a,sep) {
 return Array.prototype.join.call(a,sep);
};` то функция будет определена нами в конструкторе Array.

Comment: В итоге смысл этих функций с булев сложением? Чтобы просто не переопределять повторно если где-то определено?

Comment: _просто не переопределять повторно если где-то определено_

Comment: @Grundy хорошо.

Answer (score 2):

Оператор `||` возвращает первый из операндов, булевское представление которого соответствует значению `true`.

В коде вопроса переменная `isArray` будет равна `Function.isArray`, если `Function.isArray` определена, или `function(o) { ... }` - в противном случае.

```js
var a;
var b = 123;
var c = 456;
var d = a || b;
console.log(d);
var e = b || c;
console.log(e);
var f = b || a;
console.log(f);
```

Comment: Как работает `||` — понятно, а зачем нужна та штука из вопроса — всё ещё непонятно

Comment: То, что `Function.isArray` берётся если определена — понятно, только вот, насколько я знаю js и если мне не врёт гугл, `Function.isArray` не определено вообще никогда и нигде

Answer (score 2):

Этот код означает, что если есть стандартная функция Function.isArray, то использовать ее, а если такой функции нет, то тогда уже определить собственную функцию для проверки.

Comment: А когда Function.isArray есть? Я проверил во всех ближайших браузерах и даже в nodejs — у меня её нигде нет

Comment: @andreymal, на самом деле она должна была быть [Array.isArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

Comment: @Grundy вот если бы была она, то всё было бы понятно)

Comment: @andreymal, скорее всего опечатка :)